# using -ply family to repeat a routine a get a matrix in R

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I'm trying to repeat `rnorm` with a specified set of its argument 5 `times` using `lapply` or other `-ply` family in BASE R and store the result as a matrix such that the matrix has `times` number of rows and `n` number of columns.

Is this possible?

```
times = 5
n = 4
m = 3
s = 2
as.matrix(lapply(seq_len(times), rnorm(n, m, s)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `replicate`

```
set.seed(24)
out1 <- t(replicate(times, rnorm(n, m, s)))
```

With anonymous function using `sapply`

```
set.seed(24)
out2 <- t(sapply(seq_len(times), function(x) rnorm(n = 4, m, s)))
```

-checking

```
identical(out1, out2)
#[1] TRUE

dim(out1)
#[1] 5 4
```